# How to expose F# module's public functions to Javascript via Fable?

Tags: javascript, f#, fable-f#

Let's say I have the following f# module:

```
module Sample =
    let Add x y = x + y
    let Subtract x y = x - y
```

How do I configure Fable or Webpack so that when I include the bundle.js file generated by webpack into my index.html, I can call the module Sample's functions from javascript, like this:

```
<script>
   var myResult = Sample.Add(2,4)
</script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53722758/2225808

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help. If I use those webpack settings (libraryTarget: 'var', library: 'MyLib'), I do get the var in JS but nothing is inside that js var. In other words, for the sample module above, I tried accessing by doing MyLib.SampleLib.Sample.Add(1,2) but got an error that SampleLib is undefined (there is no child objct under MyLib)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to set up webpack to generate a "library".

In your webpack.config.js your `output` node should look like that:

```
    output: {
        path: resolve('./output'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        libraryTarget: 'var',
        library: 'EntryPoint'
    },
```

Then in order to expose a clean API to call from JavaScript, you should use an interface.

```
type Sample =
    abstract Add : int -> int -> int
    abstract Subtract : int -> int -> int

let private add x y = x + y

let api =
    { new Sample with
        member __.Add x y = add x y // You can call a local function
        member __.Subtract x y = x - y // You can implement the function directly in the interface 
    }
```

Then from JavaScript you can do something like that:

```
EntryPoint.api.Add(1, 2)
EntryPoint.api.Subtract(1, 2)
```